# Swagger-ui not work with restify but works with express

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, swagger-ui, restify

I am working on to create swagger docs for node restify APIs but it's not working .can any one help me out why this happened.
my code is as follow

### app.js

```
    require('dotenv').config();
    var restify = require('restify');
    var corsMiddleware = require('restify-cors-middleware');
    var swaggerOption=require('./app/swagger/swagger.js');
    const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-restify');
    const swaggerJSDoc = require('swagger-jsdoc');
    const swaggerSpec = swaggerJSDoc(swaggerOption.options);
    var cors = corsMiddleware({
            preflightMaxAge: 5,
            origins: ['*'],
            allowHeaders:['X-App-Version'],
            exposeHeaders:[]
          });
    /**
     * Initialize Server
     */
     var server = restify.createServer();

    server.pre(cors.preflight);
    server.use(cors.actual);
    server.use(restify.plugins.acceptParser(server.acceptable));
    server.use(restify.plugins.queryParser({ mapParams: true }));
    server.use(restify.plugins.bodyParser());
    server.get('/docs',swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerSpec))
    server.get('/api-docs',swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerSpec))

    server.listen(8080, function () {
      console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
    });
```

In my **swagger.js** file it contains options object for swagger ui and use with swagger jsdoc.
I am getting following **error** when hit this swagger url
 http://localhost:8080/api-docs.

```
 Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/var/www/html/projects/User-Workspace/node_modules/swagger-ui-restify/static/api-docs
```

Can any one please help me out with this..thank you

Comment: Any one please help me out this....Can I use swagger-ui for restify

Comment: Now I create one express app in my restify project folder and add swagger for that restify api  with different server..now we have to start two server one for Restify API and second is express app server for swagger ui ...It's working but Please let me know if someone have better solution...thank you

Comment: I also stuck in this problem. Please anyone could solve this problem..How to implement swagger with restify?